# Multiprocess a Queue and return a list

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue

So I am trying to process a queue of two zip-codes. The function where the queue is being fed is to calculate the driving and straight distance between the two zip-codes. I would like for the function to return both values (driving and straight distance) and be able append those values to a list so I can use them later. I'm fairly new to multiprocessing so I'm not sure where to go from here. I originally wasn't sure if you could pass two arguments through a pool/queue so I decided to try and put the two zip-codes into a set to be passed through the function to try and use it as one argument then pull out the necessary items separately. Please let me know if you need more information from me.

```
doc_num = []
origin_zip = []
origin_add = []
origin_city = []

destin_zip = []
destin_add = []
destin_city = []


#for i in range(14, len(data)-1):
for i in range(14, 16):   
    doc_num.append(data['AutoTable+Fit.13'][i])

    origin_add.append(data['AutoTable+Fit'][i])
    origin_city.append(data['AutoTable+Fit.1'][i])
    origin_zip.append(data['AutoTable+Fit.2'][i])

    destin_add.append(data['AutoTable+Fit.8'][i])
    destin_city.append(data['AutoTable+Fit.6'][i])
    destin_zip.append(data['AutoTable+Fit.7'][i])

distances = []

def calculate_distances(q):

        try:    
            zip_sets = q.get()
            drive = (gmaps.distance_matrix(zip_sets[1][0], zip_sets[1][1]))['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['value'] * 0.000621371
            #print(f"Driving distance:", drive_dist)

            LAT1 = gmaps.geocode(zip_sets[1][0])[0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
            LONG1 = gmaps.geocode(zip_sets[1][0])[0]['geometry']['location']['lng']
            LAT2 = gmaps.geocode(zip_sets[1][1])[0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
            LONG2 = gmaps.geocode(zip_sets[1][1])[0]['geometry']['location']['lng']

            distance = math.acos(math.cos(math.radians(90-(LAT1))) *math.cos(math.radians(90-(LAT2))) + math.sin(math.radians(90-(LAT1)))\
                                 * math.sin(math.radians(90-(LAT2))) * math.cos(math.radians((LONG1)-(LONG2)))) * 3958.756

        except:

            drive = -1
            distance = -1

        return (drive, distance)

q = Queue()

for x in range(len(origin_zip)):
    q.put((origin_zip[x], destin_zip[x]))

pool = Pool(5)
pool.map(calculate_distances, (q,))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: Currently with this code I am getting a "RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance". I was working with some earlier code and was getting a "pickling" error. At this point I'm kind of lost in the sauce. Anything will help.

Answer (score 0):

A `queue.Queue()` should not be used for passing arguments to a `pool` of worker. Instead you should directly pass an iterable (e.g. a list of the sets of arguments) to `pool.map()`:

```
# Create a list of pairs as input to pool.map() (Not needed, see below)
pairs = [pair for pair in zip(origin_list, destin_list)]
distances = pool.map(calculate_distances, pairs)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

However, the creation of the `pairs` list is not necessary in this case, as the output of the `zip` operation is an iterable anyway and can be used directly. Also, if you are running Python 3.3 or above (which I sincerly hope you do) you should consider using a context manager (`with ...`) instead of the `pool.close()` and `pool.join()` calls, giving you the following piece of code:

```
with Pool(5) as pool:
    distances = pool.map(calculate_distances, zip(origin_list, destin_list))
```

i.e., no explicit `close()` or `join()` and no intermediate list of zip codes.